# Comparison Test with Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

While I and my friend were solving the problem $$\sum \left(1- \frac {1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n <\infty$$

We found that we can solve this without using $\left(1- \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right)^n < e^{-\sqrt n} $

The process is,
$$ 0 \le  1-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}  < 1$$and we can choose the $x$ s.t. 
$$  1-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}  <x< 1$$
therefore, 
$$ \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right) ^n <x^n$$
if we take sigma,
$$\sum \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right) ^n < \sum x^n $$
and since $ 0 \le x < 1$,
$$\sum x^n$$ converges, therefore by the comparison test,
$$\sum \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right) ^n$$ this series also converges.

Is there any logical contradictions or errors in this proof?

Comment: Oops: $1-1/√n_0 <x_0 <1$. since lim $1-1/√n=1$, you can find a $n_1$ s.t. $x_0 <1-1/√n_1 <1$.

Comment: That is not **one single** $x$ you are choosing. You are choosing an $x_n$ such that $1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < x_n < 1$. The $x_n$'s depend on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You have 
$$\left( 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n} = \exp \left( n \ln\left( 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)\right)= \exp \left( n \left( - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{2n} + o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \right)$$ $$= \exp \left( - \sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{2} + o\left( 1\right)\right) \sim  \exp \left( - \sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

This is the general term of a convergent series, hence the original series also converges.

Comment: Oh, your answer is great. However, I wanted to ask that the proof I did has any logical contradictions or errors.